# Correct way to reuse a component in React?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

This is a simplified code.
Here is a button component:

```
import React from 'react'
import styles from './Button.module.scss'

const Button = (props) => {
  return (
    <button type={props.type} className={styles.btn} onClick={props.handleClick}>{props.text}</button>
  )
}

export default Button
```

I'd like to reuse this component in multiple places. My issue is that i have a form where i don't need to provide any `handleClick` logic. So i just simply omit it:

```
<form onSubmit={handleFormSubmit}  >
  *form related code*
  <Button text="Submit" type="submit" />
<form/>
```

And in places where i need some `handleClick` logic i pass it:

```
<Button text="Do Something" type="button" handleClick={()=> console.log('clicked')} />
```

Is it a correct way to reuse a component or should i have 2 different components in this case? It does not feel ok to make it reusable by not passing props. Thank you.

Comment: It's totally fine. `onClick` will just receive `undefined` and will then be ignored by React.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's perfect, in the matter of fact, making a component re-usable via it's props is the best practice, and unless this way makes a component unnecessarily complicated then don't use it, and go for the Two Components approach instead.

***Tip:*** we have a component `A`, it's already re-usable, but, we want to add another feature to it, to support an other use case, but it'll make the component complicated, in this case, building a new component `A2` is preferable.

Answer (score 1):

I believe that it is completely fine to not pass props to components. In a large number of libraries, there are default props. In the PropTypes library, you can use `defaultProps` to provide default values so the developer does not have to specify them every time.

Answer (score 0):

Sometimes it is difficult to decide. So I always go with **intent**. Every component has an intent/purpose. If we use a property to customize the behavior slightly, then it is completely fine. `Button` with an optional handle for click binding.

But when we do with some important properties which could make the component behave like a different component (different intent), then it is better to go with two components to avoid ambiguity in usage. like `ClickableButton` and `SimpleButton`.